# Datetime with autoreply post to gsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made a WhatsApp auto reply and saved it on a gsheet using the apps script.

But I am confused to post datetime automatically using the following script.

Is there something wrong with my script ?

```
function doPost(e) {
  // Open sheet
  let sheetUrl = "link gsheet";
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Rapikan data
  let req = JSON.stringify(e).replace(/\\/g, "").replace("}\"", "}").replace("\"{", "{");
  let reqJson = JSON.parse(req);
  let senderMessage = JSON.stringify(reqJson["postData"]["contents"]["senderMessage"]);

  // Mengurai isi pesan
  let parsedMessage = senderMessage.split("#");
  // ['"daftar', 'afin', '17/08/1945', 'Indonesia']
  let ulp = parsedMessage[1].trim();
  let kategori = parsedMessage[2].trim();
  let catatan = parsedMessage[3].trim().slice(0, -1);
  let datetime = new Date();

  // Create ID
  let row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  let prefixIdPendaftar = 220000;
  let idPendaftar = `B-${prefixIdPendaftar + row - 1}`;

  // Insert data
  sheet.getRange(`A${row}`).setValue(idPendaftar);
  sheet.getRange(`B${row}`).setValue(ulp);
  sheet.getRange(`C${row}`).setValue(kategori);
  sheet.getRange(`D${row}`).setValue(catatan);
  sheet.getRange(`F${row}`).setValue(datetime);



  // Respon
  let response = {
    data: [
      {
        message: `Terima kasih, ananda ${nama} berhasil terdaftar dengan ID ${idPendaftar}.`
      }
    ]
  };

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Post the supposed datetime to gsheet

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please narrow down your question or clarify your post, this way the community will have better chances of understanding your desired result and will result to better chance of having your questions answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question - isn't this line `sheet.getRange(`F${row}`).setValue(datetime);`  saving a timestamp to the spreadsheet?

Comment: yes like that, but I tried with the script the timestamp is not inputted into the sheet..

While the other values ​​are inputted into the sheet